# Display local .txt file on leaflet realtime

Tags: javascript, leaflet, real-time

I am really new in JS & Leaflet and I´m trying to use Leaflet-Realtime to display a local .txt file, with no succes.

I know that I have to convert my **.TXT** file into **GEOJSON** to be able to read it.

**FILE FORMAT:**

- Has no header.
- Only need columns 4 and 6

```
-1  06/10/2020  08:35:43    45.72125602 N   11.363634   E   198.2   M   4
-1  06/10/2020  08:35:44    45.721256   N   11.36363403 E   198.19  M   4
-1  06/10/2020  08:35:45    45.72125598 N   11.36363402 E   198.19  M   4
-1  06/10/2020  08:35:46    45.72125596 N   11.36363401 E   198.2   M   4
2   06/10/2020  08:35:50    45.72125595 N   11.3636341  E   198.2   M   4
```

For the momment what I have tried is to write the GEOJSON in the script to be able to display it, but it doesnt work:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 30,
    rotate: true
}).setView([45.64364529, 10.20162995], 17);
L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=H8dFchQ0uLgjRY4sSXUK', {
    attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var latlngs = {
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [ 45.64172279, 10.19579398],
            [ 45.64193714, 10.1958776],
            [ 45.64220345, 10.19598908],
            [ 45.6423983, 10.19606341],
            [ 45.6429504, 10.19632354],
            [ 45.64329464, 10.19658367],
            [ 45.64341805, 10.19758703],
            [ 45.64339856, 10.19838601],
            [ 45.64313876, 10.1987855],
            [ 45.64244377, 10.19869259],
            [ 45.6418527, 10.19879479],
            [ 45.6415669, 10.19715967],
            [ 45.64170331, 10.19648147],
            [ 45.64189167, 10.19615631]
        ]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}
};

// Real Time
L.realtime({
    latlngs,
    crossOrigin: true,
    type: 'json'
}, {
    interval: 60 * 1000,
    start: false
});
```

Comment: Why do you think you need leaflet realtime plugin to load your data? And also what makes you think you need to convert your data into GeoJSON?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
For what I have been searching, the two options that I found was leaflet-realtime or leaflet.liveupdate. If you know any other better and simple way to do it, can you share it?
Also, I did found any information on how to display a .txt file on leaflet.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok but what are the specifics of your use case that makes one of these plugins suitable? Is your "_local .txt file_" on a server or on the user's machine (i.e. client side)? Is it automatically modified externally? And how do you need to display the data? You seem to build a single polyline made of all your points?

Comment: Exaclty, sorry I realized that I need to give more details haha. It is from a local machine that is automatically modified externally.

Answer (score 0):

**For future users looking for an answer:**

I end up using the Leaflet Plugin 'Leaflet.Liveupdate' and works perfectly for me.

```
L.control.liveupdate ({
    update_map: function () {
        ...
    },
    position: 'topleft'
})
.addTo(map)
.startUpdating();
```

**To Parse the files into array:**

```
                getData();
                async function getData() {


                    const response = await fetch('file.txt');
           
                    // console.log(response);
                    const data = await response.text();

                    const table = data.split('\n').slice(1);
                    table.forEach(row => {

                        const out = []
                        table.forEach(row => {
                            const colums = row.split('\t');
                            const lat = colums[3];
                            const lng = colums[5];
                            out.push([lat, lng]);
                        });
```

**Full Code:**

```
L.control.liveupdate({
            update_map: function() {
                getData();
                async function getData() {


                    const response = await fetch('file.txt');

                    // console.log(response);
                    const data = await response.text();

                    const table = data.split('\n').slice(1);
                    table.forEach(row => {

                        const out = []
                        table.forEach(row => {
                            const colums = row.split('\t');
                            const lat = colums[3];
                            const lng = colums[5];
                            out.push([lat, lng]);
                        });

                        // console.log(out)
                        var latlng = [
                            out
                        ];

                       var polyline = L.polyline(latlng, {
                            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                            // color: 'red',
                            weight: 10
                        }).addTo(map);

                    })



                }
            },
            position: 'topleft',
            interval: 500 //10000 = 1 seg
        })
        .addTo(map)
        .startUpdating().stopUpdating();

});
```